# Solution verification of: show that $(S_N-I_N)_N=\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)-\int_1^N f(x)dx$ for $f$ positive and decreasing has limit in $[0,f(1)]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

> Let $f$ be a positive and decreasing function on $[1,\infty)$. Set
> $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N f(n) \ \text{and} \ I_N=\int_1^N f(x)dx.$$
> Show that the sequence $\{S_N-I_N\}$ is monotonically decreasing and its limit belongs to the interval $[0,f(1)]$.

My work: it is
$$S_{N+1}-I_{N+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} f(n)-\int_1^{N+1} f(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)-\int_1^N f(x)dx+f(N+1)-\int_N^{N+1}f(x)dx$$
$$=S_N-I_N+f(N+1)-\int_N^{N+1}f(x)dx$$
But by hypothesis $f$ is decreasing on $[1,\infty)$, hence being $1 \le n \le N$ for $x \in [N,N+1]$ it is $f(x) \ge f(N+1)$ and so $-\int_N^{N+1} f(x)dx \le -\int_N^{N+1} f(N+1)dx=-f(N+1)$, hence
$$S_N-I_N+f(N+1)-\int_N^{N+1}f(x)dx\le S_N-I_N$$
So $S_{N+1}-I_{N+1} \le S_N-I_N$, that is $\{S_N-I_N\}$ is decreasing. Since $1 \le n \le N \implies N \ge 1$, by monotonicity it is
$$S_N-I_N \le S_1-I_1=\sum_{n=1}^1 f(n)-\int_1^1 f(x)dx=f(1)$$
Moreover, from the inequalities involving integrals of positive decreasing functions on $[1,\infty)$ and summations, it is
$$\int_1^N f(x)dx \le \sum_{n=1}^N f(n) \implies S_N-I_N \ge 0$$
So, since the limit of a decreasing sequence exists, the limit of $\{S_N-I_N\}$ as $N\to\infty$ exists and taking the limit as $N\to \infty$ in the obtained inequalities it follows that
$$0 \le \lim_{N \to \infty} (S_N-I_N) \le f(1)$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yup this looks right to me, though you have a typo in the first line of your solution, you should be summing $f(n)$ not $f(x)$.

Comment: You are right, thanks for noticing the typo!